# Date and Time Python (Stuck)

Tags: python

I am Python beginner. I have a question about Date and time code:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()
print(date.strftime('date is %d%b,%Y'))
```

Now I want to print the date of my own choice. How can I do it?

For example, if today's date is (15 sep 2016) and I want to print (23 oct 1998), what should I do in order to make it work?

Comment: how can  i do that @bharel

Comment: in order to accept the answer, click the check mark below the voting buttons. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321168) for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like so:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(year=1998, month=10, day=23)
datetime.date(1998, 10, 23)
>>> _.strftime('date is %d %b,%Y')
'date is 23 Oct,1998'
```

As per [`datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) documentation, `date()` accepts a year, month and a day.

Comment: thanks mate thats helpfull  .. can i also do it for time ?

Comment: Yup. Time accepts hour, minute and seconds. You may use `datetime.datetime()` if you wish both date and time in same object.

Comment: Hi @AnonymousHacker, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize date using datetime constructor.

```
>>>import datetime
>>>d = datetime.datetime(1998,10,23)
>>>print(d.strftime('date is %d %b,%Y'))
```

Comment: cant i type 23 10 1998 ... 2nd line .. when i type error pop up . whts the reason ?

Comment: It is the order in which datetime expects in input to be %Y,%M,%D

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to take a string value as input you can use

```
from dateutil import parser

datestring = "23 Oct 1998"
customDate = parser.parse(datestring)

print(customDate.strftime('date is %d%b,%y'))
```